# How to work with multiple sed commands in aix?

Tags: sed, aix

I want to search an pattern and I need the next following line of that pattern.

In Linux I had tried as below, and it worked.

```
sed -n '/pattern/{N;p}' ouputfile.txt
```

But in AIX, this is not working and throwing error as

> 0602-404 Function cannot be parsed

How to achieve this in AIX?

Comment: You could try installing the gnu versions of those tools.  For example, http://www.perzl.org/aix/index.php?n=Main.Sed

Comment: I don't know much about aix, but if you have awk you can alternativelly do `awk '/pattern/{getline;print;exit}` or `awk '/pattern/{p=1;next}p{print;exit}`

Comment: #George Vasiliou, I understood the first usage of awk which you mentioned. in second  usage here, is **p** normal variable or is it means something ... can you make me understand .... #thank you

Comment: Requests for learning materials (tutorials, how-tos etc.) are off topic. `man sed` on your corresponding platform, as well as [sed] [aix] questions on this site would be a good starting point.

Comment: Jeff Schaller, Thank you for commenting, I just edited the question.

Comment: In second version of awk, `p` is just a temp variable - nothing special. When `/pattern/` is found then `{p=1;next}` => assign 1 to temp awk var `p` , and go to next record / next line of file without executing the rest awk code. On the next line the code `p{print;exit}` is executed. This is equivalent to `p==1` or more correctly to `p <>unset or p <>zero`; Thus if p is not zero and is not unset then `print` (the line) and `exit` awk completely.

Comment: #George, Thank you, now I understood. But small doubt. here we are using `p{print;exit}` is like an condition, when p==1 then it prints. If we don't give **p** here, It directly has to print. Here when I tried with `awk '/pattern/{next}{print;exit}` It is giving file name as output. May I know the reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing a semicolon after the `p` before the `}'

```
sed -n '/pattern/{N;p;}' ouputfile.txt
```

You could also write it stringed as multiple `-e` commands:

```
sed -n -e '/pattern/{' -e 'N;p' -e '}' ouputfile.txt
```

And the safest & clearest way is to lay it out across lines as this method affords you to place in-line comments in the sed code:

```
sed -ne '
    # lines matching pattern
    /pattern/{
        N;      # grab the next line into the pattern space
        p;      # print the pattern space holding the current+next line
    }
' outputfile.txt
```

(don't forget the `;` in between the `N`/`p` and `#` commands)

Answer (score -1):

I think SED is may not be the great option to search for strings in AIX/*nix systems. It is mostly used for editing file streams.

You need to use `grep` to search for a pattern in a file.

`grep -A 1 "pattern" file.txt`
would give you the next line after the matching pattern.

Thanks,
Arun

Comment: Not by default on AIX it won't.  `-A` is a gnu feature of grep.

Comment: The print var is different in AIX instead of Linux the correct way would be to do the following. sed -n '/pattern/,$p' $RESULTSFILE

Comment: @EightBitTony sorry, I was not aware of it.

Comment: AIX's print function in sed is the same as everyone else's. `p`